# how to convert plain text out put to html tag

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a contact form 7, where a message display after submission of contact form.
My problem occur when I tried to whole message split into two different colors. 
So can I achieve that. I make a span class to change the color of some part of string as you can see that iI posted in the end. But it is displaying without any html or css tag effect.

`**Your query has been submitted. <span style="color:green;">A member of staff will be in contact soon.</span>**`

```
`div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok span {
border: none;
font-weight: normal !important;
color: red !important font-size:24px !important;
position: relative !important;
width: 840px;
line-height: 26px;
}`
```

Hope you understand, any help would be appreciated.... Thanks

```
my html tag are not working, I have output like "Your query has been submitted. <span style="color:green;">A member of staff will be in contact soon.</span>", see there is span tag coming as plain text
```

Comment: try style="color:#00FF00;"   basically replace the word green with hex #00FF00

Comment: well, at least you have `color: red !important` css rule, so inline style won't override this rule. !important rules could be overriden only by other !important. Also it is recommended to avoid them.

Comment: For one, like others have said, you need a `;` after `color: red !important` and secondly, if you are printing the `<span>` tag you should enclose `style` in `'` single quotes because using double quotes consecutively breaks the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a semi colon after the **color: red !important**

```
div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok span {
 border: none;
 font-weight: normal !important;
 color: red !important;
 font-size:24px !important;
 position: relative !important;
 width: 840px;
 line-height: 26px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please replace this code instead of your old style...

```
div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok span {
      border: none;
      font-weight: normal !important;
      color: #ff0000 !important;
      font-size:24px !important;
      position: relative !important;
      width: 840px;
      line-height: 26px;
    }
```

I think you didn't add semicolon `(;)` in between color and font-size property..

Comment: hello, my html tag are not working, I have output like "Your query has been submitted. <span style="color:green;">A member of staff will be in contact soon.</span>", see there is span tag coming as plain text

Comment: please put my above code on your css file..it will be fine

Comment: How can it work when browser interprets span tag as plain text...??

Comment: can you put here your html tag ..?